# how to programmatically change toggle in ionic v4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to retrieve toggle state from the server and update the view accordingly 
here is the HTML for that

```
<ion-list *ngIf="this.devices.length > 0 " no-padding >    
      <ion-item *ngFor="let device of this.devices;  let i = index">      
        <ion-label color="light">{{ device.name }} </ion-label>
        <ion-toggle (ionChange)="update_state($event,device.ssid)" (ngModel)="device.ssid" color="secondary"></ion-toggle >
      </ion-item> 
    </ion-list>
```

I know I can bind an `ion-toggle` to an object in ts file using `ngModel` but i'm not getting the point how that is going to work with toggles being generated dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the ngModel two-way binding, change (ngModel) to [(ngModel)]

```
  <ion-toggle (ionChange)="update_state($event,device.ssid)" [(ngModel)]="device.ssid" color="secondary"></ion-toggle >
```

Comment: but this way all ion-toggles will be bound to a single object? I want to access all of them separately, I'm not getting how should I declare an object in ts file, will it an array or something else.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you mean by bound to a single object? You are binding each toogle to an item in the devices array

Comment: the number of ion-toggle is dynamic did you notice *ngFor right above ion-toggle?

Comment: each iteration will bind the ion-toggle to device.ssid object overriding the previous bind. all I want a snippet of TS file how dynamic toggles can be two way binded

Comment: I maybe misunderstanding you, is this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zpzlag not what you are asking for? (not ionic just angular and checkbox instead of toogle)

Comment: your stackblitz helped me a lot to figure out the problem. thanks for the effort, you saved my day today.

Comment: Glad i could help, happy coding

Comment: @MikNiller Doesn't this trigger an infinite loop if you change device.ssid in script?